# Atacar css no elemento pai

Tags: css, css3

Eu tenho essa estrutura HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th><a>Lastname</a></th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Eu precisava aplicar o CSS na `<tr>` de todos os elementos que tem o elemento `<a>`. Alguém sabe se da para fazer isso no CSS?

Comment: Não funciona :( eu já tinha tentado

Comment: Quer usar somente css?

Comment: @Nagi pode usar JQuery?

Comment: não pq eu teria que refazer a função do framework e colocar  um calback ai teria problemas la na frente com atualizações.. estou tentantado com CSS eu tentei colocar um onload no elemento mais nada :(

Comment: sabe me dizer se a algum função no JQUERY que monitora o html pois e adicionado via $('table tbody').html(RETORNO); e eu nao queria mexer no framework

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div

Comment: Se tiver um <a> dentro do <th> vc quer que o <tr> receba um estilo é isso? Ou vc quer estilizar todos os <a> dentro da tabela? Atualmente só com CSS vc não consegue mudar o estilo do Pai através do fílho.

Comment: $('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'table tbody tr', function(){
        // do your stuff

        if($(this).find('.active').length)
        {
            $(this).addClass('active_tr');
        }
    }); @N.Dias